# unable to update the id value in the database using php and sql

Tags: php, mysqli

working on a simple approve disapprove system in PHP but can't able to update the account status of the user to 0 to 1. i am getting the value in the address bar but unable to execute the SQL query
code:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
            $query = 'UPDATE project set acc_status ="1" WHERE id = "$id"';
                mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

Comment: Firstly check your database connection is working fine.

Comment: db connection is working the insertion query is working fine

Comment: try this, $query = 'UPDATE 'project' set 'acc_status' ="1" WHERE id = "$id"';

Comment: solved it, i just removed the quotes from id "$id" to just $id thank you

Answer (score 1):

Stop using query without preparing and parameter binding, because it is open to SQL injection.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query =$conn->prepare('UPDATE project set acc_status =1 WHERE id = ?');
$query->bind_param('i',$id);
$query->execute();
```

**As suggest from Dharman for report error:**

> #### How to actually use it?
>
> **Just remove any code that checks for the error manually**, all those `or die()`, `if ($result)` and such. Simply write your database
>   interaction code right away:
>
> ```
> $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO table(name, quantity) VALUES (?,?)");
> $stmt->bind_param("si", $name, $quantity);
> $stmt->execute();
> ```
>
> again, **without any conditions around**. If an error occurs, it will
>   be treated as any other error in your code. For example, on a
>   development PC it will just appear on-screen, while on a live site it
>   will be logged for a programmer, whereas for the user's convenience
>   you could use an error handler (but that's a different story which is
>   off topic for mysqli, but you may read about it in the article linked
>   above).

Reference SO:[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param)

Comment: Could you please stop printing error messages? Don't check for errors manually.

Comment: he is programming, he must see the errors after he will remove that piece of code

Comment: You never said in your answer to remove it afterwards. Anyway, you do not need it if you enable PHP error reporting. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param Other functions can fail too. You can't add ``if`` after every line

Comment: @Dharman which is your tip if query fail echo a generic error? sorry for my fault

Comment: If the query fails and you have error reporting switched on PHP will throw an error.

Comment: Which was the problem?